# Adding a field dynamically to search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am a newbie into ElasticSearch and I am trying to figure out how to achieve this:

In our Elastic Search Cluster we have documents like this:

```
{
    "hotel" : "Hilton Maldives",
    "location" : ...
}'
```

and what we want to achive is that when we search in Elastic Search, it replies with this:

```
{
    "hotel" : "Hilton Maldives",
    "price" : 100$
    "location" : ...
}'
```

this dynamic or synthetic field will come from an external service.

Of course, we can achieve this after the retrieval of all the hits of a search, but for us the performance is a must, and we would like to add this while the ES cluster is retrieving the items: that means for example, that with 100 documents on 4 shards, distributed in 4 servers, each server will add the "price" field to 25 documents (on an hypotetic match of the 100 documents)

As I understand, we need to create a plugin for Elastic Search, but after two days looking where and how, I have not found any clear reference on how to do it.

I would really appreciate any suggestion or help to this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suggest you add the "price" fields to the documents you index in Elasticsearch. When the value changes, update the documents. You might want to search on price also, and then you need it the "price" field indexed.

Comment: Hi Anton
  we can't do this, because the price is automatically calculated based on other input parameters, who is the client, source country, etc. In other words: business rules